# How Can i avoid repeated/duplicate test data or to avoid already executed data without deleting in CSV file?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, query-performance, jmeter-plugins

We have a constrain in our application, For test data providing in JMeter execution (using CSV Data Set Config element) we are not supposed to provide duplicate test data and it won't accept in all the fields. So we kept unique test data (upto 8K data for 8k concurrent users) for all the fields in CSV format.

Here I have a manual intervention, After each test execution **(i.e) 100 users, 1000 users up to 8000 users)** we need to delete each row (WRT to users in thread group) in CSV file else the duplicate data will be fetching for next execution and result will be failed.

Here my questions is,
1. How Can i avoid repeated/duplicate test data or to avoid already executed data without deleting in CSV file.
2. During JMeter test execution with CSV files, How can we specify to take the data from the respective rows. For example 101th row, 1001th row & 7999th row (which contains 8000 rows of data)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option will be using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/), its [READ](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#READ) command has `KEEP=FALSE` attribute so you will be able to feed your test with the unique data without having to physically remove it from the original CSV file.

You can install HTTP Simple Table Server plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/):

[image]

---

In general if your test doesn't need to be repeatable instead of keeping the data in the CSV file you can consider generating it on the fly using such JMeter Functions as:

- [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random)
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString)
- [__RandomDate()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate)
- [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID)
- etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. We tried the above things in our test plan but the variable accepting duplicate values also. In which properties file do we need to add KEEP=FALSE command. Could you please elaborate this KEEP=FALSE command? how to avoid duplicate values upto 8000 users.